# Can I use cordova for xbox?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, xbox-one

I can use [Cordova](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=42675) for the following platforms:

> Android 4+ iOS 6, iOS 7, iOS 8 Windows 8.0 and Windows 8.1 Store
>   Windows Phone 8.0 and Windows Phone 8.1

But can I use it for Xbox One?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this *is possible*. However only if you build for **Windows 10**. You should be able to do this by changing `Windows-target-version` in your config.xml file.

Please see [this post](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/06/03/windows-release.html) for more details.

NOTE: From my previous experience with PhoneGap and Cordova I never heard anything about publishing apps for the Xbox but this quote, from the post I linked to, definitely makes it sound doable:

> You can create a single app package that can be installed onto a wide range of devices. A single store makes it easy to publish apps across all device types - desktop, mobile, Xbox, iOT.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use Cordova to have Windows 10 apps. **But** you have to consider that cordova is a cross mobile platform. it is designed to build **apps for mobile** but **not for XBox**.

The best and recommend way by Microsoft is to use Universal windows platform (UWP) to build XBox Apps this will give you much flexibility and great UX for your XBox App.

Read more here: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/getstarted

Windows 10 Game development center: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/mt592659.aspx

Cordova doesn't have any plugins for Xbox, so your best approach is to use Universal Apps because it give you accessibility to Xbox SDK APIs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I developed web application and now trying to convert it to mobile using Cordova, so I thought I can use Cordova for Xbox too. I see other option: hosted web app using manifold.js. But probably you're right, Xbox should be separate project.

Comment: Yes your best bet is to have a separate project. 

Cordova doesn't really offer any advantage on Windows, as far as I can tell, because Windows allows for native JavaScript applications.

So you can drop the entire web project you currently have into a Windows 10 JS template, and it should work just fine.

Comment: I am just trying to provide the right strategy for your development efforts and look at the big picture beyond what can be done using cordova right now :)

Comment: @Dave, I don't think my project will work as native Windows JavaScript applications, because I use WebRTC, which works only on Chrome and FireFox.

Comment: You are correct, as Edge supports ORTC (frequently called WebRTC 2).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible a priori with Universal Windows Platform :
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/06/03/windows-release.html

Comment: in VS I have Universal Windows project template. Is it better to use it or Cordova?

Comment: If you're looking to build an app solely for use on the Xbox it's probably better to go with VS and build natively... The point of Cordova is usually to target multiple platforms with a single code base.